# rewrite rule on nginx for css js files not work

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I use laravel framework for my website on nginx server

I need to apply rewrite rule on nginx

its a sample:

```
site.com/play/gamename/css.css --> site.com/uploads/games/gamename/css.css
or
site.com/play/gamename/js.js --> site.com/uploads/games/gamename/js.js
```

and I need to know How can I define rule to do it?

my website root path is

```
/var/www/html/siteuser/
```

root directories:

```
app
storage
public
-uploads
,...
```

in my old server with apache .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|png|css|js|appcache|xml|ogg|m4a)$
RewriteRule ^play/(.+) siteuser/public/uploads/games/$1 [L]
```

I test this but not work:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html/siteuser/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        server_name .site.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                if ($uri ~ ".(jpg|png|css|js|appcache|xml|ogg|m4a)$"){
                        set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
                }    
        }
        if ($uri ~ ".(jpg|png|css|js|appcache|xml|ogg|m4a)$"){
                set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
        }
        if ($rule_0 = "1"){
                rewrite ^/play/(.+) /siteuser/public/uploads/games/$1 last;
        }


        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @MichaelHampton rewrite rule doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a `rewrite` for this at all. Use an `alias`ed `location` instead.

For example:

```
location ~* ^/play/.*\.(jpg|png|css|js|appcache|xml|ogg|m4a)$ {
    alias /var/www/html/siteuser/public/uploads/games/;
}
```

This will serve only static files with the given file extensions for URLs beginning with `/play/`, from the path given in the `alias`, using case insensitive matching. No PHP code can run from inside `/play/` in this configuration.

Comment: I need to apply it only for js css and image files

Comment: @mohammad6006 So, other files in `/play/` should not be served from the uploads directory? They should be served directly from the document root?

Comment: for example there is route url : ```site.com/play/gameid```

Comment: @mohammad6006 IN that case, you can just do a case insensitive regex match as it is now.

Comment: ```site.com/play/gamename/js.js``` 404 not found it should be ```site.com/upload/games/gamename/js.js```